# Do nightclub technitians generate value more efficient after upgrading biker businesses?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Biker businesses like the weed farm can be upgraded to run more efficient by

1. quicker generation of products from resupply,
2. generating more units of products from units of each unit of resupply and
3. raising the worth of each unit of products.

At least that's how I understand the in game description of the upgrades.

That is related to the process of resupplying the biker businesses itself by buying or stealing resupply and delivery of products actively.

**The technicians in the nightclub can generate good from biker businesses on their own. Do the biker businesses's upgrades effect the performance or efficiency of generation of goods in the nightclub, too or is their no effect from those upgrades to the nightclub?**